# Replacing static function pointer in argument by a pointer to a method in instance

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I use a third-party library that requires to have pointers to static functions passed as callback arguments. For now I have to do something like this:

```
static int MyCallback( ...)
{
    // Callback code here...
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ThirdPartyFunction( &MyCallback, ... );
}
```

What I would like to do is to replace the static callback function I have to provide by a member method of an instance of a C++ class. Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int MyCallbackMethod( ... );
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass instanceOfMyClass;

    ThirdPartyFunction( &(????), ... );
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't compile when I pass `&instanceOfMyClass::MyCallbackMethod`to `ThirdPartyFunction()`. When starting a thread (say, a *std::thread*) one passes `(&MyClass::MyCallbackMethod, this)` but in this case, the `ThirdPartyFunction` (that seems to be written in C rather than in C++ ?) doesn't allow me to pass a function pointer and an object owning the method.

On the other hand, if I declare `static int MyCallbackMethod` in `MyClass`, of course it works but I don't have an instance and it is not what I want.

My question is simple: is it possible to pass something like `(&MyClass::MyCallbackMethod, this)` (*instance method*) in place of `&MyClass::MyCallbackMethod` (*static method*)? I'm using **C++11**.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT 1**

I use libmicrohttpd (see [microhttpd.h](https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/src/include/microhttpd.h))

Function "`ThirdPartyFunction`":

```
_MHD_EXTERN struct MHD_Daemon *
MHD_start_daemon_va (unsigned int flags,
         uint16_t port,
         MHD_AcceptPolicyCallback apc, void *apc_cls,
         MHD_AccessHandlerCallback dh, void *dh_cls,
         va_list ap);
```

and `MHD_AcessHandlerCallback`, for example,  is declared as:

```
typedef int
(*MHD_AccessHandlerCallback) (void *cls,
                          struct MHD_Connection *connection,
                          const char *url,
                          const char *method,
                          const char *version,
                          const char *upload_data,
                          size_t *upload_data_size,
                          void **con_cls);
```

So I have to use a function that has this signature. I would like to use the same signature but on an **instance method** rather than a **static function**.

Comment: IMO you can't. The third party library wants a function pointer to a function with a certain  signature and you have to stick to that signature. And why do you need an instance method ? The third party library doesn't know anything about your class anyway.

Comment: Could you please show the correct signature of both the callback function and the function that is used to register that callback?

Comment: Do the `ThirdPartyFunction` allow you to pass any user-data? Like e.g. a pointer? That is passes to the callback function? Then you could make a `static` function wrapper that you pass to the `ThirdPartyFunction`, and pass a pointer to the object as the user-data, and in the wrapper use the user-data pointer and call the non-static member function.

Comment: @Michael Walz Possible, hard to "accept" however. There is no _adapter_ or something like this in C++11 that could change the signature of the member method to a static method/function???????

Comment: @dom_beau not that I know. Please clarify your question as asked by dasblikenlicht and Joachim Pileborg.

Comment: See my **Edit 1** for actual signatures of function that uses the callback and the callback itself.

Comment: `apc_cls` seems to be the user data that you retrieve at first argument of `MHD_AccessHandlerCallback`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, and `dh_cls` is probably the one for `MHD_AccessHandlerCallback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a pointer to member function in place of a pointer to a non-member or a static member function, because member functions require an object on which they are invoked. A pointer to that object becomes the implicit `this` parameter of your member function.

If you need to dispatch a call to a member function, there needs to be a way to find the object on which the function is being invoked. There are two general approaches here:

- Put the object pointer to your object in some place known to your program. Pass a static function that finds the object target, and invokes callback on it
- Rely on the API functionality that lets you pass "user data" to your callback, placing an object pointer there.

In both cases you register a static or a non-member function as a callback function to your third-party API.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
struct MyClass {
    int MyCallbackMethod( ... );
};

static MyClass *instancePointer;

static int MyStaticCallback( ...) {
    instancePointer->MyCallbackMethod(...);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MyClass instanceOfMyClass;
    // Point instancePointer to instanceOfMyClass for the static callbacl
    instancePointer = &instanceOfMyClass;
    // Register static callback
    ThirdPartyFunction( &MyStaticCallback, ... );
}
```

The second approach depends on the API. Assuming that your callback receives a `void*` that you can pass to `ThirdPartyFunction`, the implementation goes like this:

```
struct MyClass {
    int MyCallbackMethod( ... );
};

static int MyStaticCallback(void* userData) {
    MyClass *instancePointer = (MyClass*)userData;
    instancePointer->MyCallbackMethod();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MyClass instanceOfMyClass;
    ThirdPartyFunction( &MyStaticCallback, (void*)(&instanceOfMyClass));
}
```

In your situation it looks like the `cls` pointer is what's being passed back to your callback, and `apc_cls` / `dh_cls` is what *you* pass to third-party function for registration.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution seems interesting to me, I'll test it ASAP.

Comment: @dom_beau Please keep in mind that the first solution is harder to maintain, unless the object to which you send the calls is truly a singleton. In situations when there are multiple recipients it is much better to use the second approach with `apc_cls` and `dh_cls` void pointers.

Comment: Taken into account. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `ThirdPartyFunction` is defined in C, then it can't possibly be declared in such a way that you could pass a non-static member function to it.

You can only bind a regular function to a regular function pointer. So, write a wrapper function that isn't a non-static member that calls the member function. But how to get an instance on which to call the non-static member?

Well, the C Api's probably lets you pass a `void*` pointing to arbitrary data that will be passed to the callback. If it does, then you can pass the object instance as the arbitrary data.

If it doesn't then you can use a static instance or a static pointer to an instance, but those can be quite problematic because that makes the callback unusable during static initialization and makes it non-re-entrant which also makes it unusable in multithreaded contexts.

---

Update according to your edit:

Your API does support passing `void*` data to the callback (both callbacks), so I recommend that you use that.

```
* @param apc callback ...
* @param apc_cls extra argument to apc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're right about apc/apc_cls. I didn't realize I could use them this way.